# Spectrum of Laplacian on one hemisphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, angular-momentum, operators

as is well-known, the spectrum of the Laplace operator on $S^2$, computed via
$-\Delta f=\lambda f$, is positive and discrete.

What happens to the spectrum if we just take one hemisphere into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spectrum will remain discrete and non-negative (which is more accurate than positive even for the sphere) because like the sphere, the hemisphere is compact. But what the spectrum exactly is depends on how we define the problem on the hemisphere.

If we take the upper or Northern hemisphere, $0\lt \theta\lt \pi/2$, we have to define some boundary conditions for $f(\theta,\phi)$ on the boundary i.e. the $\theta=\pi/2$ equator. The simplest ones are either the Dirichlet boundary conditions
$$ f(\theta=\pi/2) = 0) $$
and the Neumann boundary conditions
$$ [\partial f / \partial \theta] (\theta=\pi/2) = 0 $$
The Dirichlet problem is equivalent to postulating
$$f(\pi-\theta,\phi) = -f(\theta,\phi)$$
which is an "antisymmetry" of $f$ under the $z\to -z$ reflection. The spherical harmonics get multiplied by $(-1)^{\ell-m}$ by this reflection. It means that $\ell-m$ has to be odd to produce the minus sign above. $Y_{\ell m}$ survive for $\ell-m$ odd.

Similarly, the Neumann boundary conditions may be imposed by extrapolating the wave function to the "even one" on the other hemisphere, and $Y_{\ell m}$ survive for an even $\ell-m$.

One may also define functions $f$ on $RP^2$, the projective sphere, which is $S^2/Z_2$ where $Z_2$ reflects all three coordinates. In this setup, we get an unoriented $RP^2$ which has no boundary. The spherical harmonics that survive are those with $\ell$ even (or $\ell$ odd if we want $f$ to have the opposite sign at the opposite point).

At any rate, the qualitative behavior of the spectrum is the same as on the sphere and about $1/2$ of the eigenstates and eigenvalues may be simply copied for any simple enough choice of the boundary conditions.